# Sharepoint Text Filter not updating List

Tags: list, sharepoint, filtering, web-parts

I have the SharePoint web part called 'Text Filter' and a list beneath. I've connected the 2 of these so that the list 'gets filters values' from the text filter. When typing a value into the text filter and apply this, the list filter appears but doesn't update the list based on these values, even though the dropdown filter option on the sharpoint list column has the value selected which was put into the text filter. Any ideas why the list isn't updating?

Thanks.

Comment: To what type of column are you applying the filter?

Comment: Single line of text, characters will start with a letter followed by 6 numbers

Comment: Another follow-up question: what version of SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013